# Oracle apex AOP Server can not be found. Check if it is running

Tags: oracle, printing, oracle-apex

We have installed the AOP on premise software and when we try to print from the application we get the error "AOP Server can not be found. Check if it is running "
The component settings for the plugins seem to be correct and AOP is running. when we load the AOP url in the browser , it works and we were also able to print some sample json from the aop url. However we are not able to print from the apex application
How can we debug this or figure out what we are missing ? does the schema require any ACL, grants for on premise ?

APEX version: 20.1

Thanks,

Comment: I would suggest you contact the AOP team directly, I have found them to be quite helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the URL entered in the component settings aop url. It needed to include the domain name as well and not just the host name and port